# How do I implement a File based Dictionary

Tags: file, streaming, io, large-files

I would like to perform the following operations on a text file.

```
Add(key, value);
Update(key, value);
Remove(key);
Contains(key);
```

The text file can become very large (100MB-500MB).

I am aware of existing solutions like the follow, but I would like to implement a local file based solution.

- Memcached
- Redis
- Etc..

Comment: What's your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) can handle key-value pairs a lot better than you can with regular text files.

Comment: Yeah it can, I need a local file though. Can't use memory.

Answer (score 0):

[memcached-like key/value cache that uses both RAM and disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080741/memcached-like-key-value-cache-that-uses-both-ram-and-disk)

Short version: there exists a disk-based memcache variants. Another point would be using noSQL databases.

Comment: I know about existing solutions like memcached and others. I'm interested in a local filebase solution