# Memcache to use disk storage?

Tags: memcached

Can Memcache be configured to use disk storage instead of RAM ?

I am running Memcache Server on High IO Amazon EC2 instance. The instance has 2TB of SSD storage available. Can I configure Memcache to use the SSD storage to store the cache contents ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this does not work. But there are alternatives as pointed out here: [memcached-like key/value cache that uses both RAM and disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080741/memcached-like-key-value-cache-that-uses-both-ram-and-disk)

Answer (score 7):

Twitter just released their Memcache on SSD, named [fatcache](https://github.com/twitter/fatcache)

Answer (score 0):

instead of memcache you could use redis witch write on disk and will use your ssd.

Comment: This feature deprecated in versions 2, and it's no longer possible.